# Как сделать, чтобы скрипт выполнялся, но не потреблял столько оперативной памяти?

Tags: php, парсер, nginx, сервер, скрипт

Есть некоторый php-скрипт, который выполняет парсинг с сайта.
В секунду он увеличивает потребление оперативной памяти сервера на 3-4мб (см. Картинку 1). Нормально ли это и что можно предпринять, т.к. оперативная память ограничена.

Также имеется статистика в списке процессов, которая показывает сколько "кушает" скрипт, возможно с этого есть шанс сделать выводы. (Картинка 2)

***Картинка 1***

[image: Картинка1]

***Картинка 2***
[image: Картинка 2]

Comment: Такие вопросы спрашивайте у автора скрипта.

Comment: @DiD к сожалению, я автор скрипта

Comment: И вообще, как бы, парсить на PHP - это не очень хорошая тактика. Все равно что сайты делать на  С++. Зачем? Ну он же создавался не для этого и совсем не приспособлен для парсинга. Возьмите вы уже puppeteer или какой-нибудь selenium наконец. Что вы до этого PHP все колхозите...

Comment: @DiD спасибо за совет

Comment: а селениум будет меньше памяти потреблять? ну ну. и на с++ тоже можно писать сайты, просто где же найти сколько людей, что бы они на нем писали:)

Comment: @KoVadim Попрошу заметить, вопросов по затратам памяти при парсинге selenium или puppeteer почти ни у кого не возникает. Вопросы по затратам памяти и ЦП почему-то возникают только при парсинге на PHP.

Comment: @KoVadim и да, selenium и тем более puppeteer у меня ни когда не жрали 5.4Gb оперативки. Хотя если руки растут вместо ног, то там и на selenium можно написать скрипт так, что повесит любой сервак.

Comment: я думаю, там просто кривенько скрипт написан. Я обратил внимание, что с и с++ разработчики присматривают за памятью. А вот php - обычно просто игнорируют, пока не прилетит от ООМ киллера.

Comment: @KoVadim так в PHP, на сколько я помню, освобождать память не имеет смысла. В умных книжках написано: хочешь освободить память, заверши работу скрипта, и вместе с завершенным процессом освободится и память. А `unset()` и другие - практически бесполезны (фактически не освобождают память, просто делают этот блок памяти недоступным).

Comment: Вроде как в последних версиях есть работающий gc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выявил проблему. При моём парсере используется phpQuery, в конце цикла парсинга обязательно нужно прописать функцию `phpQuery::unloadDocuments();`. Как только поставил, больше 1800 мб не перегружало.